# SwiftUI - Text elements not starting from same leading position

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am still a beginner in swiftUI.

Adding code and screenshot which will have explain my problem better. In the below screenshot, how can I align 'E' of first line with 'T' of 2nd line. I want both 'Text' elements to have same leading space i.e. both should start from the same position from left.

I have seen cases where people are using just one Text element and '\n' to move text to the next line and that aligns the text, but in my case I will be having more elements such as TextField and some more Text elements below these 2 texts hence I can't use the '\n' idea.

***Code:***

```
struct TestData: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("backgroundImage").resizable().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all).scaledToFill()
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                Text("Enter your Data")
                    .font(.largeTitle).bold()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-50, height: 33.0)
                
                Text("This is a very very long text to wrap on the next line. This text is of 2 lines.")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-50, height: 80.0)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                
                HStack {
                    // Contains image and textfield. Data will be entered in textfield.
                }

                // Move Text and Button elements.
            }.offset(x: -10, y: -100)
        }
    }
}

struct TestData_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestData()
    }
}
```

***Screenshot:***

[image]

Comment: It is hard to tell because of the resolution of your screen shot, but it looks to me like the text is aligned.  Visually it may not appear so because the "l" is at the left while a capital "T" has a lot of space under the cross bar before you get to the vertical stroke, however it looks to me that the left of the cross bar aligns with the left of the "l". You could put a border around your VStack to confirm

Comment: In fact, I just tried your code and indeed, if you add `.border(Color.red)` before `.offset(x: -10, y: -100)` you will see that the text is aligned correctly.  As an aside, use of screen size and offsets to position things is a bad idea.

Comment: My question is about aligning 'E' from "Enter you Data' line to 'T' from "This is a very very..." text... not about aligning 'T' and 'l'. :)

Comment: Start by not specifying frames.  To see how this is going to cause you problems select "Dynamic type variants" the canvas.  Then delete the `frame`s and the `offset` and it all aligns correctly and works with the font size variations.  Use relative modifications such as `padding` and `Spacer()` to get the layout you want.  Rather than trying to align the two `Text` elements, add spacing outside the `VStack`

Comment: e.g. try removing the `frame`s and replace `.offset(x:-10, y:-100)` with `.padding(.leading,50)`

Comment: Awesome. That made it quite easy for me and little less code. I always get confused when to use offset v/s padding. I keep playing around with both and then use whatever works best. Thanks @Paulw11!

Comment: The key difference is that padding changes the intrinsic size of things and is therefore taken into account by the layout engine. Offsets just move things around after the layout engine has worked everything out based on size. Using geometry reader (or worse, screen bounds) for layout is very much a last resort in SwiftUI.

Comment: I learnt it the hard way to not use Geometry Reader. I tried using it to scale the padding or frame values across different device sizes and it turned out to be a mess. I removed Geometry reader and the frame modifier and made changes across the app to what you suggested and everything works like a charm... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, don't set fixed frames; SwiftUI tends to work better when you let the layout engine do its thing.  Using `maxWidth`/`maxHeight` and `minWidth`/`minHeight` can be useful for giving clues to the layout engine about what you want.

Similarly with `offset` - This moves things around but doesn't change their layout bounding box, so you can end up with overlapping elements (which is fine if that is what you want).

For your layout, you can simply remove the `frame` and `offset` and use some `padding` to shift everything in from the leading edge:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
    Text("Enter your Data").font(.largeTitle)
    .bold()
                
    Text("This is a very very long text to wrap on the next line. This text is of 2 lines.").font(.callout)
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
    .lineLimit(nil)
                
    HStack {
           // Contains image and textfield. Data will be entered in textfield.
           }
}.padding(.leading,50)
```